# Is it possible to build large XSLT libraries?

Tags: xslt

I have used XSLT over many years and have tried to create medium size libraries (e.g. 50 import'ed XSLT files). I found this difficult, possibly because I didn't have useful development tools. I now generally do not use XSLT files of more than  a few hundred lines.

Are there large libraries of XSLT that are widely used? Are there IDEs and tools that support the building of XSLT libraries (e.g. analogues of Eclipse and Maven)? Or is there effectively a limit to the size of XSLT applications?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for links to two popular XSLT libraries and XSLT IDEs.

Comment: So, are you satisfied with the answer or do you have still other questions? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there large libraries of XSLT that
>   are widely used?

**Short answer**:

Yes, there are well-known and commonly used XSLT libraries like **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** and **[FunctX](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/)**.

> Are there IDEs and tools that support
>   the building of XSLT libraries (e.g.
>   analogues of Eclipse and Maven)?

**I am the author of FXSL and for almost 10 years I have been using the [XSelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator/)**.

**[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)** is another XSLT IDE (as part of many other things) that I have been using since some time.

> Or is
>   there effectively a limit to the size
>   of XSLT applications?

**There is no limit besides the RAM of a given computer**. **[XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-xslt-21-20100511/)** (only a working draft exists) offers even a **[streaming mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-xslt-21-20100511/#streaming)** for performing XSLT transformations that do not require the complete XML document to be parsed and to reside entirely in RAM.

**As an addendum, here is a summary of the functionality provided by FXSL**:

[image]

Comment: First - many thanks. I know how hard it is to generate sustainable communities. I note XSelerator depends on MSXML and so does not scale horizontally well.

Comment: I note (not judgmentally) that oXygen is a commercial product

Comment: My concern about scale was not CPU/RAM but the difficulty of managing the applications

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: The XSelerator *doesn't* depend on MSXML -- I am using it with more than 10 different XSLT processors -- both for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. It is only the Debugger that uses MSXML 3/4.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: Yes, oXygen is a commercial product, but it is quite inexpensive for individuals.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: There has been no difficulty managing FXSL applications. This is an architectural question. The functions of FXSL are like building blocks and many of them use FXSL functions that are even more generic and fundamental.